# What is wrong with this cloth?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to put cloth on a goblin model. Why is this cloth not working?
If I open another blend file and add the cloth exactly the same as this one, the cloth simulates, but this one refuses to. Please help.

[My Blend File](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52793)

Comment: Did you subdivide the cloth?

Comment: yeah, not a lot, but when I press play animation it doesn't fall like it should. Just stays stationary. Since this I remade the cloth and it works but it still bothers me, why would this work sometimes and other times absolutely nothing happens?

Comment: You do bake the simulation, right? Sometimes baking fixes it.

Comment: yeah i tried that too, still nothing. I guess I'll just pretend it didn't happen. starting over worked. I just know if I had have worked really hard or making a piece of clothing and then it just wouldnt simulate I would have been really annoyed.

Comment: Don't worry! We all make mistakes sometimes.